# SQL Server 2016 string aggregation to select only not existing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, string-aggregation

So, here is my SELECT query... it's working, but i want to get (with left join) only message types, which are NOT exists in CONFIG table:

```
SELECT      PARTNER.ID                          AS [ID],
            PARTNER.NAME                        AS [name],
            PARTNER.GLN                         AS [GLN],
            IIF(CONFIG.DIRECTION=0,'IN','OUT')  AS [Direction],
            COUNT(CONFIG.ID)                    AS [count config]
,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + message_type.message_type
        FROM message_type
        WHERE message_type.id not in (0,7,8,11,12,14,15)
        ORDER BY message_type.id
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')

              
FROM        PARTNER LEFT JOIN CONFIG ON PARTNER.ID=CONFIG.PARTNER_ID_EXT 


WHERE       PARTNER.ID  IS NOT NULL AND PARTNER.CHARSET IS NOT NULL
AND PARTNER.NAME NOT LIKE 'TEST%'

GROUP BY    PARTNER.ID, PARTNER.NAME, PARTNER.GLN, CONFIG.DIRECTION
HAVING      COUNT(CONFIG.ID) not in (5,11,16,20)
ORDER BY    [name] asc, [Direction] asc
```

[image: output]

> > > > **UPDATED**

My sample DATA:

[sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4a323e09559e0df4e192eeb6fd825e05)

I want to display the message types, which are MISSING from CONFIG.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Correlate your subquery by adding `message_type.{Your Column} = CONFIG.{Your Column}` to your `WHERE`?

Comment: @Larnu yes, but then i have to add "config.message_type_id" to my "GROUP BY".. and then i will have multiple rows.

Comment: Then maybe that's the wrong column; we don't know we have no sample data, and no expected results. You need to correlate the query, and that's the best we can suggest without that.

Comment: The earliest SQL Server version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017, which has the `STRING_AGG` aggregate method

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text not images) would help immensely

Comment: Added sample data and expected output.